# which table save Downloadable-Product link and sample-title

Tags: magento2, downloadable, link, sample, title

When i add/Edit downloadable Product, I `Can't get Link and Sample-Title` and **Links can be purchased separately checkbox value**.

I need details in which table it get saved/stored ? And how it is store ?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This three are **Set as an Attributes**

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

$this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

public function getlinktitle($productId)
{
  $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
  $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',$productId);
  foreach($collection as $product)
  {

    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 

      if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=='links_title')
      {
        $attribute_title['link']=$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); 
      }
      if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=='samples_title')
      {
        $attribute_title['sample']=$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); 
      }
      if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=='links_purchased_separately')
      {
        $attribute_title['seprate']=$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); 
      }

    }
  }
  return $attribute_title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically product stores in **catalog_product_entity** table and its **type_id = downloadable**

Its follow the **eav structure** so below is the details where url and other details stored.

1. url link stored in **downloadable_link** table with reference to
   **product_id**
2. And its price stored in **downloadable_link_price** table
3. its title stored in **downloadable_link_title** table
4. its sample stored in **downloadable_sample** table.

Comment: Sir, as i mention Heading Title as above image, its **not in this tables** which u list-out !

Answer (score 0):

Value is stored in table catalog_product_entity_int with attribute ID 125. You can check attribute ID from table eav_attribute`

SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id` ='125'